# YUV format invertion colors

Tags: image-processing, yuv

I have image in YUV and I want to get image with invert colors. How can I get invert colors for YUV, if I don't want to use convert to RGB?

Comment: what is an inverted colour?

Comment: In RGB it's (255 - R, 255 - G, 255 - B)

Answer (score 3):

On an empirical level, using **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows, it would seem that you need:

```
Y' = 255 - Y
U' = 255 - U
V' = 255 - V
```

So, if I make a 4x1 pixel mini colour-swatch going from blue to magenta in 3 equal steps like this and dump it as text:

```
convert -size 4x1 gradient:blue-magenta -depth 8 -colorspace YUV txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 4,1,65535,yuv
0,0: (7493.93,61340.8,26214)  #1DEF66  yuv(29,239,102)
1,0: (14022.1,58129.5,39648.7)  #37E29A  yuv(55,226,154)
2,0: (20550.2,54918.3,53083.4)  #50D6CF  yuv(80,214,207)
3,0: (27078.3,51707.1,66518)  #69C9FF  yuv(105,201,255)
```

[image]

If I then take that same little colour-swatch and invert it and show it in YUV:

```
convert -size 4x1 gradient:blue-magenta -depth 8 -negate -colorspace YUV txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 4,1,65535,yuv
0,0: (58041.1,4194.24,39321)  #E21099  yuv(226,16,153)
1,0: (51512.9,7405.46,25886.3)  #C81D65  yuv(200,29,101)
2,0: (44984.8,10616.7,12451.7)  #AF2930  yuv(175,41,48)
3,0: (38456.7,13827.9,-983.025)  #963600  yuv(150,54,0)
```

You can see all the values are `255-previous`.

If I make a slightly more thorough test and try a different gradient of red-yellow:

```
convert -size 4x1 gradient:red-yellow -depth 8 -colorspace YUV txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 4,1,65535,yuv
0,0: (19584.4,23133.9,73071.5)  #4C5AFF  yuv(76,90,255)
1,0: (32403.3,16820.7,61821.4)  #7E41F1  yuv(126,65,241)
2,0: (45222.2,10507.4,50571.2)  #B029C5  yuv(176,41,197)
3,0: (58041.1,4194.24,39321)  #E21099  yuv(226,16,153)
```

[image]

And the same again but inverted:

```
convert -size 4x1 gradient:red-yellow -depth 8 -negate -colorspace YUV txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 4,1,65535,yuv
0,0: (45950.6,42401.1,-7536.52)  #B3A500  yuv(179,165,0)
1,0: (33131.7,48714.4,3713.65)  #81BE0E  yuv(129,190,14)
2,0: (20312.8,55027.6,14963.8)  #4FD63A  yuv(79,214,58)
3,0: (7493.93,61340.8,26214)  #1DEF66  yuv(29,239,102)
```

And again the resulting values are all `255-previous`.

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm. `for(int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) byteArray[i] = (byte) (255 - byteArray[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

I derived the formula:

```
Y' = 251 - Y
U' = 256 - U
V' = 256 - V
```

So if YUV -> RGB and Y'U'V' -> R'G'B' then R + R' = G + G' = B + B' = 255. And Y'U'V' forms the inverse color.

Comment: I think all your numbers should be `255`.